# Can't see 3D model file in Xcode editor

Tags: xcode, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I want to do some work with ARKit, but when I add .dae or .scn to `art.scnassets` group in my Xcode project, it doesn't show anything in Xcode 10.1 editor (see the picture), so I can't edit the model. Adding light or other things doesn't help.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: Where did you get your `.dae` file?

Comment: I download model from poly.com, its .obj file and transfer to .scn file when i want to edit it in XCode, but the demo app(from AR Kit 2) which has a ship model, it can run on my iphone, and i can see the 3Dmodel on my iphone while it also can't show in the XCode editor.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose, you've successfully imported your `dae` model into Xcode's Scene graph (and this `dae` model doesn't have flipped poly normals) but you can't see it because your model has no texture.

Here's a simple example of **ostensibly empty scene**:

[image]

But this scene isn't empty. To see what it contains you need to click <kbd>Show Scene Graph View</kbd> button at the bottom of Xcode's UI and choose geometry's group in a list.

[image]

If you can't still see your whole `dae` model in Scene graph just press <kbd>F</kbd> on a keyboard for framing. And now you're able to assign a `jpeg` or `png` texture for your mesh via `Diffuse` slot of Material's properties.

[image]

In your case 3D object is called **`maze`**. Just select it, press <kbd>F</kbd> on your keyboard to frame your model in Scene graph and then assign a texture via `Diffuse` slot in Utility area (press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd> to activate a Utility area).

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help and I tried your method, unfortunately it still doesn't work, when i click "show the material inspector", it shows "not applicable", and also no attributes, no animation, no constraints message in the list.

Comment: Try other `dae` files and if they don't work too, reinstall Xcode. But if other files do work, you've got a problem with `maze.dae`.

Comment: Hello. Have you found a solution to this problem? Please tell me the solution. I have Xcode 11.3.1 and the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, @GURU, whom do you address your question to, me or Nora?

Comment: @andyFedo, for you. I am trying to find a solution, but have not found it yet.  I do not know why the model is not displayed

Comment: There are four possible issues: (1) inverted normals of a model, (2) wrongly assigned UV map for texture, (3) absence of a texture itself, or (4) 100% transparency of a shader.

Comment: What 3D authoring tool are you using for making a model, its shaders and UV textures for it?

Comment: I haven't created a model, I use free ones.

Comment: So, then load this model in Unity or other game engine and see how it behaves. If it behaves the same way as in Scene Graph – it's a model's problem, otherwise it's a SceneKit problem.

Comment: i have same problem any help please? until this ship.scn not shown